# ormlite query using datetime by eq()

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I want to update datetime is equal.

**Here are my case.**

> 1. selet object.  this object has updatedate field - datatime
> 2. call web api
> 3. update sync status field of (1) if updatedate is same.

This is for preventing overwrite after another task's update during http call.

Here is my code.

```
Apply.java
public Date getUpdateDate() {
    return updateDate;
}

....
UpdateBuilder<Apply, Integer> updateBuilder = applyDao.updateBuilder();
try {
        if (apply.getUpdateDate() == null) {
            updateBuilder
                    .where()
                    .eq(Apply.APPLY_SEQ_NO, apply.getApplySeqNo())
                    .and()
                    .isNull(Apply.UPDATE_DATE);
        } else {
            updateBuilder
                    .where()
                    .eq(Apply.APPLY_SEQ_NO, apply.getApplySeqNo())
                    .and()
                    .eq(Apply.UPDATE_DATE, apply.getUpdateDate());
        }

    updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(Apply.SYNC_STATE, newSyncState2);
    updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(Apply.UPDATE_DATE, new Date());
    affectedRows = updateBuilder.update();
```

It translated as below by ormlite.

```
update Apply set syncsate = 'S' where applyseqno = 1 and updatedate = ?
```

But, result is always failed.

updatedate's value is `2018-06-14 09:49:02.743000`

I guess java.util.date does not match the format.

How can I compare exact sample datetime by ormlite datetime?